# Microsoft.Identity.Client returns malformed result

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Working with the [Xamarin Sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native) app after authenticating the AuthenticationResult returns a properly, and the `PublicClientApplication` stores the user.

However if I update the Tenant, Client ID and Scope in the sample and then attempt to authenticate against my own B2C instance the AuthenticationResult is malformed and the `PublicClientApplication` still has 0 users stored which causes `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` to fail when the app is relaunched.

Note: I've also updated the AndroidManifest/Info.plist with the msal{My ClientId}

UPDATE:

To clarify by Malformed I mean that the Access token is blank and the expiration a default DateTime which is the likely cause of the PCA not storing the now authenticated User. As mentioned `AquireTokenSilentAsync` will fail on subsequent calls since there is no user stored by the PCA. However if I take the IdToken from the `AuthenticationResult` and pass that as a Bearer token to my API it is recognized as a perfectly valid token.

Comment: Did you include the B2C policy id in there somewhere?

Comment: I made sure to add a SUSI policy with the same exact name as the sample, as well as the other policies in the sample

Comment: In Azure AD B2C, did you register your API application, and then grant access by your Xamarin application to this API application?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett I've tried this both having different applications and enabling a Native Application on the application I have configured for my API. Not really sure what you are referring to by granting access. (i.e. where that needs to occur...)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not able to get an access token, but you are able to get an id token.

> However if I update the Tenant, Client ID and Scope in the sample and
>   then attempt to authenticate

Did you set up the scopes properly through the portal? You need to publish the scopes for an API and then grant the scopes to the api for the native app.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-access-tokens